# How to not run a chunk that will have an error

Tags: r, image, r-markdown, rmagick

I am working to knit an html file with images that will be updated weekly. I am using an Rmarkdown file to specify file path to images as so:

```
---
title: "test"
output:
 html_document:
   toc: true
   toc_depth: 2
   toc_float: true
   theme: flatly 
params: 
  user1: "C:/Users/blah/Desktop/Discrete-event-simulation-concepts.png"
  user2: "C:/Users/blah/Desktop/Discrete-event-simulation-concepts5.png"
---
```

I will be generating these report weekly so one week we might have an image for user 2 and one week we might not have an image for user 2. So I know that I can knit and get an html running with setting error = TRUE. But that still displays the error message in the html output where the image is missing. Is there a way to set up a condition where if a file is not present, that chunk will not run where I read in the file? Im using magick package to read in each image from it path specified in the params.

Comment: Yes.  You can use r variables to set chunk options.  See [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/chunk-variable.html).  So test for the existence of the file and store the result in a variable.  Then set, say,  the `eval` to the value of that variable for the chunk that relates to `user2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass `R` statements to knitr options as well, as in the following.

````
---
title: "test conditional chunks"
output: html_document
params: 
  user1: "C:/Users/blah/Desktop/Discrete-event-simulation-concepts.png"
  user2: "C:/Users/blah/Desktop/Discrete-event-simulation-concepts5.png"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


```{r condition 1, echo=FALSE, eval=file.exists(params$user1)}
# plot image
```

```{r condition 1, echo=FALSE, eval=file.exists(params$user2)}
# plot image
```
````

Comment: For the path, can I just put a path to the folder that has all the various images or do I need to specify the specific image?

Comment: well... there might be better ways of solving your problem, but in order to conditionally run or not run a chunk, the `eval` option has to be set to TRUE or FALSE and this condition will have to be identified somehow. `file.exists()` can also be used to check if a `path` exists. Depending on how you are dealing with your images, you can probably write a function to plot all images in a given folder and if a image does not exist, it will just not be dealt with at all.

Comment: probably the best would be write a new question all together on "how to display all images in a folder with RMarkdown" and also provide more detailed info on how you are using `rmagick` to display those images.

Comment: If this solves your question,consider marking as solved :)